# Eliminar dato de matriz

Tags: c#

Tengo este metodo:

```
static void muestro(int[,] matriz) //MOSTRAR APUESTAS
        {
            for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.GetLength(0); fila++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < matriz.GetLength(1); col++)
                {
                    Console.Write(matriz[fila, col] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

y aqui lo invoco en el main:

```
case 5:
    Console.WriteLine(listado de apuestas: ");
    mostrar(matriz);

    break;
```

Pero a la hora de listar no me muestra el nombre del apostante, y por ende cuando elimino al apostante no me elimina la apuesta, ya que cuando vuelvo a listarla sigue apareciendo, necesito que me muestre todas las apuestas de todos los apostantes

Comment: nombre es un vector???? y despues lo pasas como si no fuera vector??? esto siquiera compila??? tampoco entiendo tu logica, y menos tu error. podrias aclarar todo eso por favor?

Comment: no, no me compila el case 3, por eso mi duda, no entiendo si el método y cuando lo invoco esta bien, el case 1 carga los datos manuales perfecto, pero cuando estoy armando la sentencia invocando al método eliminar me tira error y no me deja compilar, esa es mi duda. Sepan disculpar recien me inicio y tengo muchas dudas, gracias

Comment: estoy ingresando nombres(filas de la matriz), y 5 números(columnas de la matriz), para cada nombre 5 números, eso es el método cargarjugada y el case 1, ahora quiero eliminar la fila con su apuesta para el nombre y apellido pedido

Comment: no va a compilar nunca porque eliminar recibe un string (nombre) y le estas pasando un vector (nombre). y no es el unico error.

Comment: Ok, serias tan amable de ayudarme?

Comment: supongo que esto es tarea para la facultad? si pides un problema en particular, solucionamos ese problema en particular.. ahora te escribo la respuesta de porque no te compila.

Comment: En este sitio ayudamos con problemas puntuales, pero en general no hacemos la tarea de la gente. fijate que ahi te solucione el problema, pero no se si la logica es correcta. Eso es lo que queda para vos.

Comment: claro, lo se, pero si hago una consulta es porque no entiendo la logica, y mas si recien empiezo, solo pido ayuda y una guia, ya probe con pasarle los vectores con tope, pero sigue dandome problema, pienso que el problema esta en el metodo, pero a eso voy, no me doy cuenta que

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de tus errores es que en la función recibes una arreglo de `string` en vez de un arreglo de `int`.
Otro error es que en esa lista estás buscando el nombre y el apellido, cuando nunca le pasas como parámetro tu lista con nombres y apellidos.

Lo que tienes que hacer es que cuando encuentre a la persona con ese nombre y apellido, vayas recorriendo las apuestas en una posición atrás. Así sólo eliminas la apuesta de la persona indicada.
Y si vas a eliminar la apuesta de esa persona, también sería necesario eliminar sus datos de nombres y apellidos, porque si no la relación entre las posiciones de los arreglos estaría desfasada.

Intenta con esto:

```
static bool eliminar(int[] lista, string[] nombres, string[] apellidos, string nombre, string apellido, ref int tope) //ELIMINAR EN UN ARRAY
    {
        bool e = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tope; i++)
        {
            if (nombres[i] == nombre && apellidos[i] == apellido)
            {
                e = true;
                for(int j = i; j < tope - 1; j++)
                {
                    lista[j] = lista[j + 1];
                    nombres[j] = nombres[j + 1];
                    apellidos[j] = apellidos[j + 1];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return e;
    }
```

**EDITADO**

Okay, si lo que necesitas es que te muestre la apuesta de cierta persona, lo que tendrías que hacer es encontrar en qué índice se encuentra dentro de tus arreglos `nombre[]` y `apellido[]` y usar ese índice en tu matriz de apuestas:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nombre.count(); i++)
{
    if(nombreIngresado == nombre[i] && apellidoIngresado == apellido[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("La apuesta de {0} {1} es de {2}", nombre[i], apellido[i], matriz(i, i));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61127/discussion-on-answer-by-emmanuel-lg-eliminar-dato-de-matriz).

Comment: @Emmanuel-lg  como estas? cambi mi codigo, ya pude resolver lo de mostrar y mostrar todo, pero estoy trancado en un eliminar, te puedo pedir ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Sin siquiera revisar todo el codigo, este no compila por que la funcion `Eliminar` recibe como parametros `strings`, y le estas enviando vectores.

```
static bool eliminar(string[] lista, string nombre, string apellido, ref int tope)
...
string[] nombre;
string[] apellido;
...
eliminar(vector, nombre, apellido,  ref tope)
```

deberias pasar:

```
eliminar(vector, nombre[tope], apellido[tope],  ref tope)
```

Pero desconozco si la logica de estos parametros es correcta.

Comment: si, asi lo probe tambien, pero me sigue marcando error "algunos argumentos no validos"